# Lost a Fusion drive boot disk

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, fusion-drive

i can see my Fusion Drive disks (ssd+hdd) in Terminal:
[image]

But i lost it in the boot and cant boot MAC OS.
(please see album with photos on https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqzhj.jpg )

I cant repair my system, when i click "check disk" on Fusion Drive it is nothing to do.

And if i want to re-install Yosemite, system did not see my Fusion Drive disks, only bootcamp (i have a windows too).

Any solution please?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `diskutil cs list`

Comment: yes, look at this please, http://imgur.com/hZZWJV3